# ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

While compiling native code-base, I'm getting the following error -

```
<NDK-HOME>/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:235:68: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
<NDK-HOME>/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:235:70: error: '\__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type
...
```

With tons of repetitions.

Platform related details are as below -

```
Native OS: Windows 7 (64 bit) with Cygwin64
NDK Version: r9c
```

A similar problem has been reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64325). However, even after modifying `LOCAL_CFLAGS`, I couldn't find the intermediate files as suggested.

Was wondering if some of you have faced this problem already and if so, do you guys have a work-around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, finally got rid of these __NDK_FPABI__ errors and my native code compiled just fine. Indeed, there were subtle hints in the intermediate files (*.i and *.ii) as suggested by Andrew in the link on my previous post; these are usually related to finding appropriate headers. Once relevant changes were made, things worked like a charm.

Few things I learned while debugging this issue -

- The problem was related to header files. Certain headers were being picked up from **/usr/include** which otherwise should have been picked up from **$NDK_HOME/platform/$ANDROID_VERSION/$ARCH/usr/include**. Making necessary changes in the Android makefile fixed the issue for me.
- Always resist the temptation of adding hot-fixes to NDK files. This will make your life a lot easier in the long run.
- One should look for the intermediate files (*.i, *.ii, *s and few others) in **$PROJECT_ROOT**, instead of **$PROJECT_ROOT/jni** (assuming native code lies there).
- The latest release of NDK, namely [**ndk-r9d**](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Revisions) fixes some of the issues with __NDK_FPABI__ related errors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't find the *.i or *.ii intermediate files - any tips? Edit: nevermind, you already gave the hint to look in $PROJECT_ROOT instead of $PROJECT_ROOT/jni; found it now!

Comment: It seems I have the same issue, where certain files are being picked up from C:\\cygwin\\usr\\include instead of from the NDK path you gave. However, I am unsure about how to make "necessary changes in the Android makefile" to fix the issue.

Comment: Okay, it looks like adding these lines to Android.mk fixed this problem:

`LOCAL_CFLAGS := -IC:\Users\Tony\src\android-ndk-r10c\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include \
-IC:\Users\Tony\src\android-ndk-r10c\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include\sys`