# ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type. Version 2

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have exactly the same problem described here [ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106857/error-ndk-fpabi-does-not-name-a-type) but I don't understand the answer or I am doing it wrong; I need more details.
This is my enviroment:

- Trying to compile a .so (thridparty) in order to use it in my Android app. This is a standalone lib, not in any Android project (not in project/jni)
- Host OS: Ubuntu 12.10 x86
- Android NDK version r9d

What I have done is:

- Open lib.so's Makefile -> change paths to /usr/include to $NDK_HOME/platform/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include (in previous link, I don't understand the meaning of "Android makefile")
- Add LOCAL_CFLAGS += -save-temps

So, I don't understand the meaning of "Android makefile" in this standalone lib and where to search (and what to look) the *.i *.ii *.s files

Any help? Thank you

P.D: I would like to comment in related topic but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem linking header file (sys/cdefs.h) from `$NDK_HOME/platform/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/sys` to `$NDK_HOME/platform/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include`
and changing the source file that launches the error from `#include <sys/cdefs.h>` to `#include <cdefs.h>`

Sure there must be better solution, but this was enough for me.