# Android Studio: ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm with the same error as these links to build the OpenCV Face Detection example for Android:

[ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106857/error-ndk-fpabi-does-not-name-a-type)

[ERROR: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type. Version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339489/error-ndk-fpabi-does-not-name-a-type-version-2)

I'm sorry for asking the same question, but the answers wasn't clear to me. I understood that the error occurs because Android Studio is using the libraries from /usr/include instead of the libraries from the NDK. However, I don't how to correct.

Here are my files:

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include /home/marcos/Downloads/Eclipse_Android_OpenCV/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 23
LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT := gnustl_static

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

**build.graddle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv.samples.facedetect"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "detection_based_tracker"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkLibsToJar
    }

    task ndkLibsToJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild', description: 'Create a JAR of the native libs') {
        destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
        baseName 'ndk-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from(new File(buildDir, 'libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
        into 'lib/'
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        println('executing ndkBuild')
        commandLine "/home/marcos/Downloads/Eclipse_Android_OpenCV/android-ndk-r12b/ndk-build",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```

And here are the errors:

```
Error:(856, 5) error: '__NDK_FPABI__' does not name a type
Error:(36, 2) error: #error Bionic header ctype.h does not define either _U nor _CTYPE_U
Error:(62, 35) error: '_CTYPE_U' was not declared in this scope
Error:(63, 32) error: '_CTYPE_L' was not declared in this scope
Error:(64, 32) error: '_CTYPE_U' was not declared in this scope
Error:(64, 37) error: '_CTYPE_L' was not declared in this scope
Error:(65, 32) error: '_CTYPE_N' was not declared in this scope
Error:(66, 33) error: '_CTYPE_X' was not declared in this scope
Error:(66, 38) error: '_CTYPE_N' was not declared in this scope
Error:(67, 32) error: '_CTYPE_S' was not declared in this scope
Error:(68, 32) error: '_CTYPE_P' was not declared in this scope
Error:(68, 37) error: '_CTYPE_U' was not declared in this scope
Error:(68, 42) error: '_CTYPE_L' was not declared in this scope
Error:(68, 47) error: '_CTYPE_N' was not declared in this scope
```

Does anybody know how to correct it?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you set the APP_PLATFORM to android-9 in the Application.mk? My installation of NDK r12b does not contain any platforms for API 8

Comment: I still got the same error :( Do I have to clean or anything else?

Comment: are you sure you have a device supporting hardware FPUs? Can you try removing the `APP_ABI` line from your Application.mk?